# Две формы повелительного наклонения некоторых глаголов являются равноправными?

Tags: стилистика, морфология, глаголы, аспектология

Некоторые глаголы имеют две формы повелительного наклонения, например:  **портить: порти/ порть, корчить: корчи/корчь, чистить: чисти/чисть.**

Можно предположить, что у этих глаголов особенная фонетика: ударение на первом слоге и две согласные в середине слова.

Но **точно ли они стилистически абсолютно равноправны**, как это указывается в орфоэпических словарях?

Comment: *ударение на первом слоге* — **закупори – закупорь**

Comment: *и две согласные в середине слова* — **высыпи – высыпь**

Answer (score 2):

> Можно предположить, что у этих глаголов особенная фонетика: ударение
>   на первом слоге и две согласные в середине слова.

Не надо ничего предполагать. Все уже сто раз описано и зафиксировано Розенталем и Еськовой.

> Варианты — с неударным окончанием -и и с нулевым окончанием
>   (последние всегда пишутся с ь на конце) воз­можны в трех случаях:
>
> если глагол имеет неударное окончание первого лица единственного числа и перед окончанием повели­тельного наклонения выступает
>   согласная щ или группа согласных, в которой вторая согласная не л, м,
>   н или р: таращу - таращи и таращь, порчу - порти и порть, а также:
>   чисти и чисть, горби и горбь, корчи и корчь и др.;
>
> если ударение в повелительном наклонении падает на слог левее того, который предшествует окончанию: от­купори и откупорь, полакомись
>   и полакомься, уведоми и уведомь, замусори и замусорь и др.; \
>
> если глагол имеет ударную приставку вы-, а соответ­ствующий бесприставочный, а также все другие приста­вочные имеют повелительное
>   наклонение с нулевым окон­чанием: выстави и выставь - ср. ставь,
>   поставь, переставь, а также: выкраси и выкрась, выглади и выгладь,
>   выправи и выправь, выброси и выбрось, вырежи и вырежь, высыпи и высыпь
>   и др.
>
> Многие глаголы, обладающие признаками, о которых сказано в
>   перечисленных трех пунктах, образуют повели­тельное наклонение только
>   с окончанием -и: объезди, за­кончи, улучши, наперчи; застопори,
>   упорядочи; вызволи, выпяти, вышколи, выспори и др.

[Еськова "Словарь трудностей русского языка..."](https://books.google.ru/books?id=vFimCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA504&lpg=PA504&dq=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%20%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8&source=bl&ots=wlLownEgZ2&sig=bbtNI3ZKU4d2jip7Of_a_vqJ1Is&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiVqpn21uraAhUMXCwKHSr3DhEQ6AEIKzAB#v=onepage&q=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%20%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8&f=false)

> Но точно ли они стилистически абсолютно равноправны, как это
>   указывается в орфоэпических словарях?

**Абсолютной** стилистической равноправности не бывает в принципе. Словари обычно исповедуют принцип первого приближения, когда равноправными считаются варианты, если выбор из них не связан напрямую с требованиями какого-то конкретного стиля из числа основных (научный, официально-деловой, публицистический, разговорный, художественный) и/или профессиональными, диалектными или просторечными особенностями. При таком подходе "равноправные" варианты могут сколь угодно отличаться частотностью использования, но не стилистическими особенностями. Рассматриваемые вами формы вполне удовлетворяют этому критерию. Сомнения ваши связаны скорее всего именно с частотой использования вариантов, но не стилистикой.

Answer (score 1):

Не думаю, что такие варианты  абсолютно равноправны стилистически. Что обе формы - норма,  это да, но одна из них книжная норма.

Параллельные формы имеют многие глаголы, не только перечисленные, чаще с приставкой ВЫ-, но и с другими тоже: высунь-высуни, выставь-выстави, высыпь-высыпи, выкинь - выкини, выбрось-выброси, очисть - очисти, испорть-испорти, где вторые формы имеют устарелый или книжный хар-р.

Сюда же и порти/ порть, корчи/корчь,  чисти/чисть. Формы на - И книжные, формы на -Ь нейтральные. Видимо, это связано с редукцией суффикса -И  в заударном положении.

Стилистические колебания имеются в образовании ещё некоторых форм повелит. наклонения: доить, кроить, поить, утаить в лит. яз. образуют формы на -и (напои, выдои); в разг. речи, просторечии и фольклоре – форму без окончания на -й (Напой ее чаем, баловница).

Просторечный характер имеют формы поди (вместо пойди), обойми (вместо обними), езжай и даже едь (вместо поезжай).

Comment: В словаре на пару порти/порть нет стилистических пометок (книжн. , разг.), а мне казалось, что форма "не порть" является разговорной, это касается и многих других пар  (выстави - выставь).  Отсюда и возник вопрос. И после всех ответов я всё-таки сомневаюсь, что в формах с нулевым суффиксом не присутствует разговорный оттенок. Мне кажется, что здесь противопоставлены нейтр. и разговор. стили, а не книжный и нейтральный. Или в любом случае нулевой суффикс  снижает стиль речи. Но в словаре это не отражено.

Answer (score 1):

*Абсолютного равноправия* не бывает. Основанием для выбора слова может стать *любое* различие. В данном случае имеет место

а) различное количество слогов - выбор влияет на ритмичность речи, в случае же стихотворной строки это особенно важно;

б) окончание на "и" в потоке речи лучше стыкуется с последущими согласными, особенно если в начале слова их больше одной (не порти впечатление - не порть его).